# Plotly double-click unzoom not working for me

Tags: zooming, plotly, double-click

Double click does not work for me to unzoom a Plotly plot.

I have tried Firefox, Chrome, Edge and Opera on my Windows 10 PC.

This applies across all Plot.ly demo sites, including R-based ones and Python based ones and others.

It fails 100% of the time.

It also fails from the code I am developing using R both at the distributed version and at ‘4.8.0.9000’.

Yet, double-click works fine for me on sites using other libraries including Dygraph, and also on the following test site: https://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse.html

I know that Plotly double-clock unzoom works for others, so I tried it on an Android phone using the Puffin browser in trackpad mode, which provides a double click capability, and it DOES WORK for me there.

So I know that the basic capability is there. Why exactly it is not working on my PC, I have no idea. It is a Logitech M705 mouse. I tried various Windows mouse speed settings and they made no difference. As I mentioned, double click works ok with other JavaScript libraries and mouse click test sites.

I see that previous reports have been made of timing sensitivity in the double-click detection code. Perhaps my environment just happens to reproduce the problem nicely? If this seems plausible, I would be more than happy to gather any evidence that would be useful.

Any help appreciated.

(I previously posted here: https://community.plot.ly/t/double-click-unzoom-not-working-for-me-at-all/17286)

Comment: This was asked a while back, but I thought I would mention that doesn't work for me unless I set the `doubleClickDelay` in `config`.  Using this setting works great for me: `{doubleClickDelay: 1000}`

Comment: @Kat where do you have to put this setting?

Comment: There's no language assigned to this question, so I'm going to assume that you're asking about JS (if using a different language, just let me know). One method is when you call to plot `Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {doubleClickDelay: 1000});`. There are other methods, [you can see examples of them here](https://plotly.com/javascript/configuration-options/). If you have questions, let me know.